# comparing two JSON API responses requested by two different users. Spotify API

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

The goal is to create a platform where two users can request Spotify data then responses are compared. I already have one piece of the puzzle solved, ie. for a single user, to access their spotify data, implemented the OAuth flow and all. The logic for comparison, I havent really looked at that piece yet. Firstly, was wondering how I'd be able to access one endpoint for a response{which I have already implemented), save that response and use a different endpoint for another user to get response, and perform logic comparison of both responses. I was thinking about using `sessions` but I got lost.

This is what I have so far.

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.home, name="home"),
path("login/" , views.login , name="login"),
path("authorize/", views.callback, name="redirect"),
path("liked/" , views.liked, name="liked"),
]
```

`views.py`

```
def login(request):
    authorize_url = oauth.get_authorize_url()
    return redirect(authorize_url)

def callback(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    if code is not None:
          token = oauth.get_cached_token()["access_token"]
          request.session["token"] = token
          return redirect(reverse("liked"))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse("login"))

def liked(request):
    sp= Spotify(auth=request.session.get("token"))
    results = []
    iter = 0
    while True:
         offset = iter * 50
         iter += 1
    curGroup = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=50, offset=offset)['items']
    #yet to complete logic for display


   def home(request):
      template_name="display.html"
      return render(request, template_name)
```

`display.html`

```
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN</a>
```